# Find the distance of point from a line passing through a circle

Tags: circles

I am looking for a solution to the problem shown in the below image

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LVCa.png)

**Known values:**

1. Radius of the circle = r
2. Length of the green line = 0.3 * r
3. Distance of dot(point) from the center of the circle = a

**Value to find:**

1. Length of the red line (X)

Please let me know if any additional information is required. Thank you.

Comment: It is not at all clear that the given lengths constrain the length of the yellow line at all. Does the wave in the background matter?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking? Is this a question about hydrodynamics, where you consider the breaking point of wave? Otherwise I am really not sure how to interpret

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have modified the problem image and the description. I hope this change will make the question clear. Sorry for the unclear problem statement earlier.

Comment: What is known about the dashed line (the end point of the red line)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Nothing is known about the dashed line. But what information about the dashed line is helpful?